# CodeIgniter - creating forms with .html link

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to create a simple website with 5 pages which contains 2 simple contact us forms.

The links should be `www.yoursite.com/contact.html` and after submitting it should go to `www.yoursite.com/success.html`. Please help, I have searched a lot for it but couldn't find anything

[edit]

I have a different controllers for different forms but in the links i don't want the controller name but only the view name.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is change the apperance of the URLs, then you could use [CodeIgniter's routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html). You'll most likely also want to remove `index.php` from the URL, more information is available in [CodeIgniter's user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html).

For example, if you have a controller named `Contact` with an `index()` function that loads the view for the contact form, and another function `success()` that loads the success page view:

- Then this route, in `application/config/routes.php` would map the URL, `www.yoursite.com/contact.html` to your `Contact` controller.

  `$route['contact.html'] = "contact";`
- This route would map `www.yoursite.com/success.html` to the `success()` function within the `Contact` controller.

  `$route['success.html'] = "contact/success";`

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Codeigniter URLs to have ".html" appended to them for some reason, you should modify your `application\config\config.php` file and change

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

to

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

You can see [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) for more info.